# What does "I'd fry first" mean

Tags: american-english

The expression "*I'd fry first*" is from the 1941 film **Maltese Falcon**. In a scene where a detective calls his secretary to inform her about the death of his partner (colleague) the conversation goes like this:

```
          Hello, Effie?

          It's me.

          Now, listen, precious.

          Miles has been shot.

          Yeah, dead.

          Now, don't get excited.

          Yeah.

          You'll have to break the news to Iva. I'd fry first.

          And keep her away from me.

          That's a good girl.

          Now, get right over there.

          You're an angel.

          Good-bye.
```

The full script can be found [here](http://archive.is/MdsmC#selection-51.4940-51.5383).

So what does "I'd fry first" mean in this context? I cannot really connect any of the definitions listed [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fry) to this context. Thus, I believe this should be a slang of some sort?

Comment: "fry" was short-hand for being executed in the electric chair  - a common method of court ordered execution in that period

Answer (score 2):

When he says "I'd fry first" he means he would rather be electrocuted in the electric chair than tell Iva that Miles (her husband) has been shot. When people are electrocuted in that way, the body is heated considerably and a sizzling sound like frying meat is said to be audible.

Comment: The other plot element is that Spade has been having an affair with Ida Archer.

Answer (score 1):

"Fry" was slang for being electrocuted by electric chair.

"I'd fry first" means "I'd rather die than that"...

So, basically that is an exaggerated way of saying "I don't want to be the bearer of bad news and bear the outburst of anger that is likely to provoke".

The electric chair was the most common form of capital punishment in the united states at the time of those lyrics, and it wasn't terribly uncommon with what looks like 150 executions a year around that time despite US population well less than half our current population.

[image]